# Enabling bluetooth on Compaq Presario C504EA

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, compaq, presario

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Compaq Presario C504EA (wiping off the old Windows Vista install), and I am trying to enable Bluetooth.

I have had a look on rfkill list all, the results are:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

When you open *System Settings | Bluetooth*, it says `Bluetooth is disabled`, whether Bluetooth is switched to on or off.

Edit: the results of `uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
rob@rob-Presario-C500-RT154EA-ABU:~$ uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Linux rob-Presario-C500-RT154EA-ABU 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:30:34 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
[    0.103205] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   22.560190] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   22.560311] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.560319] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.560324] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.560334] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.668875] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.668892] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.668900] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   22.788640] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.788647] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.788656] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.878953] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

Results of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Any thoughts? Many thanks

Comment: Please edit to include results for `uname -a; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  thanks

Comment: Added results for uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm', thanks

Comment: You forgot results for `lsusb` Thanks

Comment: From what I have seen, the computer doesn't have a bluetooth device, or the kernel can't detect it.  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On viewing `uname -a; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` and `lshw` on the terminal, there is no mention of Bluetooth capabilities, so it would appear that the Compaq Presario C504EA is one of the models that wasn't Bluetooth enabled.